# Storing files permanently

Tags: android

The code below stores the file temporarily (in cache memory,I guess) but I need to store the file permanently, what should I do?

```
public void downloadFile(){
            StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child("cliff.jpg");
            File localFile = null;
            try {
                File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
                localFile = File.createTempFile("images", ".jpg", cacheDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Log.i("msg", exception.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: define *permanently*

Answer (score 0):

How permanent are we talking? Should the data persist if the app is uninstalled? One solution is to store the data in internal storage (accessible only to the app and is removed when the app is uninstalled) by changing:

```
File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
```

to

```
File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
```

Comment: I need to store the files permanently even if app is uninstalled. Before i used DownloadManager for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file that's easily accessible by yourself and other apps, you should get the root of your external storage and create folder there.. with something like this...

```
File externalRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (externalRoot .getAbsolutePath() + "/parentFolder/childFolder");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");
...
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
...
```

Remember you should check if the storage is writable or not. This will be visible to other apps and if you don't want this

use `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();` that will give path like `/data/data/com.package/files`

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the image, you have to write it to the internal or external storage by doing so:

Instead of:

```
File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
localFile = File.createTempFile("images", ".jpg", cacheDir);
```

use:

```
File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
localFile = new File("images.jpg", cacheDir);
```

I do not know how `StorageReference` from firebase works, but I deduct that `.getFile` streams the contents to the file. In that case this code should work